# In Search of a Soulmate

Tags: code-golf, array, decision-problem

Given a nonempty finite list of integers, output a *truthy* value if there are exactly two equal entries and all other entries are distinct, and a *falsey* value otherwise.

#### Examples

```
truthy:
[1,1]
[1,2,1]
[1,6,3,4,4,7,9]
 
falsey:
[0]
[1,1,1]
[1,1,1,2]
[1,1,2,2]
[2,1,2,1,2]
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

Comment: I suppose we can't assume that the integers will always be less than 10?

Comment: Yes except if your language does not support any larger integers.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean by *consistent*?

Comment: Are the truthy and falsey values returned required to be the same regardless of the input, or could different falsey or truthy values be returned?

Comment: No they need to be truthy and falsey as defined.

Comment: Saw this on the top of HNQ & thought we’d reached the final interpersonal.se question

Comment: @gntskn Saw this on the top of SE's homepage and thought the same.

Comment: Allowing more than one soul mates couple would have add a bit of challenge, everyone is just posting code about removing duplicates and check that the length drop to the original length - 1.

Comment: @Walfrat Post it as your own challenge. Also such feedback is usually appreciated in the sandbox.

Comment: Are all values non-negative?

Comment: Yes you can assume that.

Answer (score 23):

## Python 3, <s>30</s> 28 bytes

```python
lambda m:len({*m})+1==len(m)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYvNCsMgEITveYo9uq2ExvSHBvIkbQ4WDRXUiEohlD67VUkY2P1mZtet8b3YPs0wwjNpbl6Cgxm0tOR7MD88duNYjMGkjFt8hLCGZl48aGUlKFt8G6JQtvWSC4JtcFrF0gaCQwMAzisbyUzkh2tSCkRMj452U5Mn2/aV9vScdaP37E8122@K2EasEqu0p6z@XqY/)

`{*m}` casts the list to a `set` object, an unordered list of items without duplicates. Doing this will always decrease the length of the list by the number of duplicates in it. By computing how much the length has changed, we can easily tell if the list had a single duplicate and return the result of the test.

<sup>-2 bytes thanks to ovs.</sup>

Comment: Exactly the solution I had, but forgot about the `{*m}` shortcut instead of `set`, well golfed!

Comment: [27 bytes for the negation](https://tio.run/##NYvbCsIwEETf@xX7mNUYbOoFC36J9iHSFAO5kQShiN8em9AysHtmZtfP6e1slye4wzNrYV6jANNracl3Z354KGRw32ZlvAsJ4hybyQXQykpQtngW06gsC1KMBFn0WqXSRoJ9AwA@KJvIRORHaFIKRMyPlrZDs0y@7gvt6GnRld4Wf6zZdlPEV@KVeKUt5fX3PPwB). (Falsey when it should be Truthy, etc)

Comment: Here's another weird way to do it (also negation): `lambda m:~-len(m[len({*m}):])`

Answer (score 11):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 4 bytes

```
εṠ-u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv6vkKtR/KipsUjz0Lb/57Y@3LlAt/T////RhjqGsVxA0ghKm@kY65gAobmOJZBvABaDqQFBIyjLCMwyArNgokZgvaaxAA)

### Explanation

```
εṠ-u  Implicit input.
   u  Unique elements.
 Ṡ-   Delete them from input, counting multiplicities.
ε     Is the result a singleton list?
```

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 34 bytes

```hs
f x=[1|a<-x,b<-x,a==b]==1:1:(1<$x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwjbasCbRRrdCJwlEJNraJsXa2hpaGVppGNqoVGj@z03MzFOwVUjJ51IAgoKizLwSBRWFNIVoQx3DWEwxI6yiZjrGOiZAaK5jiSFrgEU9drNB0AiruBEWcSOwOHYdRmD3mMZy/QcA) Based on [H.PWiz' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145064/56433).

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>8</s> 5 bytes

```
QL‘=L
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/Q51HDDFuf/4fbHzWt@f8/2lDHTMdYxwQIzXUsY3UUgAJAGAsA)

## Explanation

```
QL‘=L  - Main link, argument L (a list)   e.g [1,6,3,4,4,7,9]
Q      - Deduplicated elements                [1,6,3,4,7,9]
 L     - Length                               6
  ‘    - Increment                            7
    L  - Length of the input                  7 ([1,6,3,4,4,7,9])
   =   - Are they equal?                      1
```

If the output values can be any consistent values, then `QL_L` works, which outputs `-1` for truthy and any other non-positive number for falsey (thanks @JonathanAllan)

Comment: `QL_L` would output `-1` for truthy and some number less than `-1` or `0` for falsey (e.g. `[1,6,3,4,4,7,9,9,9]` would return `-3`, while `[1,6,3,4,7,9]` would return `0`).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Oh yeah. I guess the examples I tested it on all happened to return `-2`.

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>7</s>, 6 bytes

```
&=sp4=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/X822uMDE9v//aEMdMx1jHRMgNNexjAUA)

One byte saved thanks to @Guiseppe!

Explanation:

```
&=  % Table of pair-wise equality comparisons
    %
    % [1 0 0 0 0 0 0
    %  0 1 0 0 0 0 0
    %  0 0 1 0 0 0 0
    %  0 0 0 1 1 0 0
    %  0 0 0 1 1 0 0
    %  0 0 0 0 0 1 0
    %  0 0 0 0 0 0 1]
    %
s   % Sum each Column. Stack:
    %
    % [1 1 1 2 2 1 1]
    %
p   % Product of the array. Stack:
    %
    % [4]
    %
4=  % Compare the stack to '4'
```

Comment: Since `s` is `sum` and `sum` sums along the first non-singleton dimension (columns), and the matrix is symmetric, couldn't this just be `s` instead of `Xs`?

Comment: @Giuseppe Ah, TIL. Thankyou!

Answer (score 5):

## JavaScript (ES6), 30 bytes

```
a=>new Set(a).size==a.length-1
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@cn1ecn5Oql5OfrqHxP9HWLi@1XCE4tUQjUVOvOLMq1dY2US8nNS@9JEPX8L@mRrShjpmOsY4JEJrrWMZqav4HAA)

Answer (score 4):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>15</s> <s>12</s> 11 bytes

*Thanks to Neil for saving 1 byte.*

```
D`
Mm2`^$
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@qEZyg898lgcs31yghToXL8P9/Qx1DLkMdIzBppmOsYwKE5jqWXAZAPkQOBI3AtBGQNgLTEBEjsHpTAA)

Input is linefeed-separated. (The test suite uses comma-separation for convenience.)

#### Explanation

```
D`
```

Deduplicate the lines in the input, which removes any integer that has appeared before (but leaves the surrounding linefeed(s)).

```
Mm2`^$
```

Count the number of empty lines, which is equal to the number of duplicates we removed, but only consider the first two matches. So the output will only be `0` (no duplicates), `1` (one duplicate), `2` (two or more duplicates).

```
1
```

Make sure that exactly one duplicate was removed.

Comment: Save a byte by limiting the newline match to 2, so that the input to the third line is always 0, 1, or 2, simplifying the test. (Annoyingly you can't use ``A`.`` to count newlines, because it drops the last one.)

Comment: @Neil Thanks, the limit is a neat idea. I also tried using `A\`.`, but the problem is rather that you can't distinguish a single empty line from having no lines at all. Maybe I should consider terminating `A` and `G` output with a linefeed if there are any lines. Although that should probably be an option since I can imagine that linefeed being annoying in other scenarios.

Comment: Matching a single empty line is easy - that's just `^$¶`.

Comment: @Neil No, I mean that the output of `A` is identical regardless of whether it retains a single empty line or discards all lines.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant by "drops the last one" - it returns one fewer empty line, but then you can't distinguish between 0 and 1.

Answer (score 4):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

```
=&#0,=
```

`=` check every element for equality with every unique element, creates a matrix with **m** rows for **m** unique elements.
`0,` add an empty row on top.
`=&#` does the number of rows equal the length of input?

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P81WT8FWTdlAx/Z/anJGvkOag52CoYKhtaGCEZg0UzBWMAFCcwVLawMgHyIHgkZg2ghIG4FpiIgRWL3pfwA)

Comment: I think you can replace `.~` with `=`

Comment: @H.PWiz Nice, edited.

Answer (score 4):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 25 bytes

This is not using a `group` or `unique` approach as many of the other answers, but rather the "cartesian product" of all possible comparisions.

```matlab
@(x)nnz(triu(x==x',1))==1
```

#### Explanation

```matlab
             x==x'        %create a matrix where the entry at (i,j) compares whether x(i) == x(ju)
        triu(x==x',1)     %only consider the strict upper triangular matrix
    nnz(triu(x==x',1))    %count the number of nonzero entries
@(x)nnz(triu(x==x',1))==1 %check whether this number is actually 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNCMy@vSqOkKLNUo8LWtkJdx1BT09bW8H9iXrFGtKGOoY6xjomOaazmfwA)

And because no program would be complete without a convolution (thanks @LuisMendo for fixing a mistake):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 40 bytes

```matlab
@(x)nnz(~conv(sort(x),-1:2:1,'same'))==1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f/fQaNCMy@vSqMuOT@vTKM4v6gEKKCja2hlZGWoo16cmJuqrqlpa2v4PzGvWCPaUMdQx1jHRMc0VvM/AA)

Comment: You inspired me to come up with [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145092/31516) approach :)

Comment: @StewieGriffin I think the [MATL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145053/24877) answer used your exact approach:)

Answer (score 4):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 8 bytes

Simple implementation of checking whether `len(set(list)) == len(list)-1`:

```
LtvuL^=#
```

Explanation:

```
       \ Implicit: Put all input on stack
Ltv    \ Get the stack length - 1, save in auxiliary stack
u      \ Remove non-unique elements
L      \ Get the new length
^=     \ Compare with the previously saved length
#      \ Print result
```

This works as the length will only decrease by 1 if there was only exactly 1 non-distinct integer in the initial list.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/9@npKzUJ85W@f///9GGOmY6xjomQGiuYxkLAA)

Comment: Wow, haven't seen a Pushy answer in ages! +1

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing Pushy will never die. It will only come back stronger.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>32</s> 31 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @JarkoDubbeldam*

```r
cat(sum(duplicated(scan()))==1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKO4NFcjpbQgJxPISU3RKE5OzNPQ1NS0tTXU/G@oYPgfAA)

Reads from stdin, writes to stdout.

`duplicated` iterates through the list, replacing the values of `l` with `TRUE` if that value occurs earlier in the list, and `FALSE` otherwise. If there's a unique pair of soulmates, there should be exactly one `TRUE` value, so the sum should be `1`.

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRKO4NFcjpbQgJxPISU3RKE5OzNPQ1NS0tTXU/P8fAA)

Comment: @JarkoDubbeldam ah, of course. Good to see you again! It's been a while.

Comment: Been busy with some other stuff, not sure I'm completely back yet.

Comment: @Giuseppe, I just read this question and immediately thought of your Original Approach.... Very nice!  I would have never thought of the `scan()` approach.

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 10 bytes

```
1=-/#'1?:\
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxNj+FqwyAUhf/7FMIG20Cr3iQtVcYeJAtUMm1C07hFAwlje/YZ25BxQL9z77kXtVK8UvbwJN7kO0JBfj+W8+8gLcZ4Uid3Uc8nq9tOTWpWw0v1EzOlwEKJKgFsuMcZzqMO+HgrEa74rbUMbIhhM7AaSOZfD9K6YrGIoSaETy8Zq92HObvO7nzQ9cVMdaP7s9nV7sq+RuND63rPRF7wjLO2p97ooW6os1RT78buqoOJPxjG0MwSlYLEh8YT7veeZCSPOpBjhTCyuvNmyfHUXdOL4E6QCBKtVUhbigr9AUhbWkw=)

A tacit version of `{1=(#x)-#?x}`.

- `1?:\` run a distinct-do-scan for one iteration, returning a two-item list containing the original input and the distinct items of the input
- `#'` take the count/length of each item in that list
- `1=-/` is the difference between the counts one?

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 8 bytes

```
2=*/#'=:
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxNj/1qwyAUxf/3KYQN9oGpepO0VOmThEDFaROaxi0aSBjbs8/YhowD+jv3nntRK+D0Tp9eTgKhIL6fq/l3EBZjPMmzu8rXs1VtJyc5y+Gt/omZimMueZ0ANtzjHBdRB3y8lwiT7N5aBjbEsBlYDSTzrwdpXblYRFETwqcXlGr3YS6uszsflL6aSTeqv5iddjf6NRofWtd7youS5Yy2feaNGnSTOZupzLuxu6lg4g+GMTSzQBUn8aHxhMe9Jzkpog7kWCOMrOq8WXIsddf0IngQJIJEaxXSlrJGf4TrWbs=)

Checks if the product of the counts of unique elements is 2. This works because the only way to get the product of 2 is (1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 2) in some order.

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell), <s>40</s> 37 bytes

```powershell
($args|sort -u).count-eq$args.count-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gvTy0qzkjNyfn/X0MlsSi9uKY4v6hEQbdUUy85vzSvRDe1ECwM5Rn@///f8L/Rf0MA)

The `Sort-Object` command (alias `sort`) with the `-u`nique flag pulls out only the unique components of the input. For example, for input `@(1,3,3,2)`, this will result in `@(1,2,3)`.

Thus, we just need to make sure that the `.count` of this object (i.e., how many elements it has) is `-eq`ual to the `.count` of our input array `-1` (i.e., we have exactly one duplicate entry).

*Saved 3 bytes thanks to Sinusoid.*
*Fixed bug thanks to TessellatingHeckler.*

Comment: Can you use the get-unique alias 'gu' instead of group to reach the same result?

Comment: @Sinusoid Yes, we can. Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work on the second test case `1,2,1` - `get-unique` only works on pre-sorted input. How about `($args|sort -u).count-eq$args.count-1` which is also 37 but does work for all the test cases, if you call it like `f 1 2 1` instead of `f 1,2,1` ?

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Ah, good catch. All of the testing I did was with pre-sorted input. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
{¥_O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/@tDSeP///6MNdcx0jHVMgNBcxzIWAA)

Outputs `1` as truthy, any other non-negative integer as falsy. In 05AB1E, `1` is the only truthy number (thanks @Emigna for the insight!).

#### Explanation

```
{       Implicit input. Sort
 ¥      Consecutive differences
  _     Boolean negate
   O    Sum. Implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

## Ruby, 32 bytes

```
->(s){s.uniq.length==s.length-1}
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! Because this is code golf, you need to include the byte count of your program. I've taken the liberty of doing it for you this time.

Comment: How about `Array#size`?

Comment: You can get down to 26 bytes by using `->s{s.uniq.size==s.size-1}`

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 6 bytes

```
qtlQl{
```

**[Verify all the test cases.](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=qtlQl%7B&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C6%2C3%2C4%2C4%2C7%2C9%5D%0A%5B0%5D%0A%5B1%2C1%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C2%5D%0A%5B1%2C1%2C2%2C2%5D%0A%5B2%2C1%2C2%2C1%2C2%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D&debug=0)**

- `l{` - Gets the number of unique elements.
- `tlQ` - Gets the length of the input list, decremented.
- `q` - Checks equality.

## 7 bytes

```
q1l.-Q{
```

**[Verify all the test cases](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=O&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B1%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C6%2C3%2C4%2C4%2C7%2C9%5D%0A%5B0%5D%0A%5B1%2C1%2C1%5D%0A%5B1%2C1%2C1%2C2%5D%0A%5B1%2C1%2C2%2C2%5D%0A%5B2%2C1%2C2%2C1%2C2%5D%0A%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%5D&debug=0)**

Answer (score 3):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 35 + 18 bytes

+18 for using `System.Linq`.

```cs
n=>n.Distinct().Count()==n.Length-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY6xDoJAEERr@IotIYFLsEVoNFaamFhYEIrzPHET3Iu3i8YQvv2EhGammXkzhnPjvA0DI3Vw@bHYlzoivcvY9JoZzt51Xr9gjCMWLWjg4/AOJ42UsPi51bSgfcfpEolWwmEgs0WSps3g5lxfwwOqQFVNao8sSEaSVO3cQLNXFamjpU6eeRHKeEXsHLHrrbp6FDs/sskjIfud10YoMthkixZTmpbxNIU/)

**67 byte alternative without Linq:**

```cs
n=>new System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<int>(n).Count==n.Length-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pc6xCsJAEEXR2nzFlAnEhdhq0ghqoSCksBCLdR2Tgc0s7IyKhHx7jCD25z6ek7kLEUfnrQgcY2ii7aBPZqJWycEz0A0OljgVjcTN@QI2NpJ9yax@i2JnNg92K2I9X3K4huAruEM5clkxvuBn1sF7dEqBxWyRMZIzOyttjQrftko5m9CDtSzZ7JEbbefFuEz@PUvwaE6RFPfEmN7TaX6600ORwyKHYsiyZTIM4wc)

Answer (score 3):

### Excel, 42 bytes

**Danish language version**

```
=TÆLV(A:A)=SUM(--(FREKVENS(A:A,A:A)>0))+1
```

Assumes each integer from the list in separate cell in column `A`.
If we were allowed for inconsistent *falsey* values, we could save 3 bytes:

```
=TÆLV(A:A)+SUM(-(FREKVENS(A:A,A:A)>0))
```

**English language version (44 bytes)**

```
=COUNTA(A:A)=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(A:A,A:A)>0))+1
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ċ@€`QṢ⁼1,2
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8//9It8OjpjUJgQ93LnrUuMdQx@j///@GOmY6xjomQGipYw4A)

a longer but different approach

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>6</s> 5 bytes

```
{¥>ΘO
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f@/@tBSu3Mz/P//jzbUUTDTUTDWUTABI3MdBctYAA)

```
{¥>ΘO   # example input:               [1, 6, 3, 4, 4, 7, 9]
{       # sort                      -> [1, 3, 4, 4, 6, 7, 9]
 ¥      # get deltas                -> [  2, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2 ]
  >     # increment                 -> [  3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3 ]
   Θ    # truthify (only 1 gives 1) -> [  0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0 ]
    O   # sum                       -> 1
```

`1` being the only truthy value in 05AB1E, we can stop here. (Thanks @Emigna for pointing that out.)

To get only two distinct values, we can optionally add:

```
     Θ  # equals 1?                 -> 1
```

Comment: If it is okay to return any falsey value for the falsey cases, you can skip the `Θ`, as `1` is the only truthy value in 05AB1E.

Comment: @Emigna Thanks! I was not sure whether it was approved by the OP, but I guess it is.

Comment: I'm afraid you need to revert to the previous solution as `¢` will not work. It would count `[19,4,4,9]` as false and `[19,9]` as true since it finds the `0` in `10`.

Comment: @Emigna Thanks for spotting that. I think that's fixed.

Comment: `{¥_O` should be okay as well.

Comment: Yes, but now that's [Luis' answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145058/58563).

Comment: Ah, didn't see that. And Riley took your old answer. Guess you'll have to stay here then unless there is another strategy that can be used.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes

```hs
f x=sum[1|0<-(-)<$>x<*>x]==2+length x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwra4NDfasMbARldDV9NGxa7CRsuuItbW1kg7JzUvvSRDoeJ/bmJmnoKtQkFRZl6JgopCmkK0oY6hjrGOSex/AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 36 + 1 (`-a`) = 37 bytes

```perl
map$k{$_}++,@F;@a=keys%k;say@a+1==@F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z83sUAlu1olvlZbW8fBzdoh0TY7tbJYNdu6OLHSIVHb0NbWwe3/f0MFQwVjBRMF03/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6yYCAA)

Comment: may be golfed `@k{@F}++;say@F==1+keys%k`

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
gIÙg-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f8/3fPwzHTd//@jDXWMdIx1THRMYgE)

```
g     # Get number of elements in input
 IÙg  # Get number of unique elements in input
    - # Subtract
```

In 05AB1E 1 is the only truthy  value, so for a truthy result there must be exactly 1 duplicate element removed by the uniquify.

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 37 bytes

```hs
f x=sum[1|a<-x,b<-x,a==b]==2+length x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/P02hwra4NDfasCbRRrdCJwlEJNraJsXa2hpp56TmpZdkKFT8z03MzFOwVUjJ51IAgoKizLwSBRWFNIVoQx3DWEwxI6yiZjrGOiZAaK5jiSFrgEU9drNB0AiruBEWcSOwOHYdRmD3mMZy/QcA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) / MATLAB (with Statistics package / toolbox), 21 bytes

```matlab
@(x)nnz(~pdist(x))==1
```

Anonymous function. Input is a column vector. Output is `true` (displayed as `1`) or `false` (displayed as`0`).

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzL69Ko64gJbO4BMjRtLU1/J@mEW1orWAYq8kFYRkhc8ysFYytFUzAyNxawRIiYQCXR9EJQUbIfCM43wjGR1FiBDPfNFbzPwA)

#### Explanation

`pdist(x)` computes a vector of Euclidean distances between all pairs of rows from `x`. It considers each pair only once (order of the two rows doesn't matter), and doesn't consider pairs formed by the same row twice.

In our case `x` is a column vector, so Euclidean distance between two rows is just absolute difference between the two numbers.

`~` is logical (Boolean) negation, `nnz` is number of nonzeros, and `==1` compares to `1`. So the result is `true` if and only if there is only one pair that gives zero distance.

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, <s>39</s> 26 bytes

```
!a=sum(a.==a')==endof(a)+2
```

### Explanation

The code generates a 2-dimensional table of booleans, which is then collected using the sum function, counting the number of same-element pairs in the cartesian square of A. Then this is compared to the length of the string plus two, and the quantities are equal only when there is exactly one repeat character.

This code redefines the NOT operator.

Comment: `!a=sum(a.==a')==endof(a)+2` saves a few bytes. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@/9fMdG2uDRXI1HP1jZRXdPWNjUvJT9NI1FT2@h/Wn6RQllqcgmQysxT0Ig21DGM1VEAUkYwhpmOsY4JEJrrWIIEDCCicHUgaARjGoGY0UZgFlzYCGyAaawmF2dBUWZeSU6ehiLESk0uoEv@AwA "Julia 0.6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Jq 1.5](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), <s>53</s> 25 bytes

```
length-(unique|length)==1
```

Inspired by [Riley's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/145030/in-search-of-a-soulmate/145061#145061) and much shorter then my original solution.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8Hx1tqGMYqwMkjaC0mY6xjgkQmutYAvkGYDGYGhA0grKMwCwjMAsmagTWaxobGx1b8z8nNS@9JENXozQvs7A0tQbC1bS1Nfz//19@QUlmfl7xf13dvNKcHN3MvILSEiCnKLFcN7@0BMgBAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), <s>23</s> 26 bytes

```matlab
@(x)prod(sum(x==x'))==4
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0KzoCg/RaO4NFejwta2Ql1T09bW5H9aflFuYolCcn5uQWJyCZdqSVFpSUalFVeaRrShjmGsJoRhhGCa6RjrmAChuY4lUIhLNS0xpzgVosEApgZJJwgaIXOQZIxgMkZgDpJCI7AlprGa/wE)

The `x==x'` part was inspired by [flawr's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145046/31516). This is longer than Luis' answer, but it doesn't use any toolboxes.

#### Explanation:

This is an anonymous function that takes a vector `x` as input, and compares it to itself transposed. This will give a matrix where all diagonal elements are `1`, and any off diagonal elements signals that there are duplicates elements.

The sum along any given column shows how many duplicates there are of that number. We want two of the numbers to have a duplicate, so we two values equal to two, and the rest unequal to two.

If we take the product of this matrix, we'll get `4` if there are only two equal elements (`2*2*1*1*1*1*...`), and something other than `4` if there are no duplicates, or more than two.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 46 bytes

```
<?=count(array_unique($argv))==count($argv)-1;
```

Counts the number of entries in [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) and compares it to the number of unique entries. If the former is higher than the latter by 1 then truthy, else falsey.

[Try it on eval.in!](https://eval.in/878751)

Comment: Do you have to use the variable name $argv can you not just use $a instead?

Comment: @dading84 `$argv` is the list of command line parameters. So: no, he cannot just use `$a`.

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 7 [bytes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```apl
1=≢-≢∘∪
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///39D2UeciXSB@1DHjUceq/2mP2iY86u171DfV0/9RV/Oh9caP2iYCecFBzkAyxMMz@H@agqGOIReINILSZjrGOiZAaK5jyfWodw1QzAAsDlMHgkZQlhGYZQRmwUSNwPpNAQ)

Explanation:

```apl
1=≢-≢∘∪  ⍝ Monadic function train
    ≢∘∪  ⍝ Generate a list of unique items in the input,
         ⍝ and return the length of that list
  ≢-     ⍝ Take the length of the input and subtract the above
1=       ⍝ If the difference is 1, true, otherwise false
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Uiua](https://uiua.org), 7 [bytes](https://www.uiua.org/pad?src=U0JDUyDihpAgK0BcMOKKlwpEZWNvZGUg4oaQIOKHjOKKjy0x4pa9wrEu4o2Y4ouv4oav4oqCwq8x4qe74ouv4qe7LOKHjOKItSjihpjCrzHii68rMjU2KSAtQFwwKzEKJnAg4oqCIjggYml0IGVuY29kaW5nOlx0IiBTQkNTICLih4ziio8tMeKWvcKxLuKNmOKLr-KGr-KKgsKvMeKnu-KLr-Knuyzih4ziiLUo4oaYwq8x4ouvKzI1NikiIOKKgitAXDDih6ExMjkiLiziiLY74oiYwqzCscKv4oy14oia4peL4oyK4oyI4oGFPeKJoDziiaQ-4omlKy3Dl8O34pe_4oG_4oKZ4oan4oal4oig4qe74paz4oeh4oqi4oeM4pmt4ouv4o2J4o2P4o2W4oqa4oqb4oqd4pah4oqU4omF4oqf4oqC4oqP4oqh4oav4oaZ4oaY4oa74per4pa94oyV4oiK4oqXL-KIp1xc4oi14omh4oi64oqe4oqg4o2l4oqV4oqc4oip4oqT4oqD4oqZ4ouF4o2Y4o2c4o2a4qyaJz_ijaPijaQh4o6L4oas4pqCzrfPgM-E4oiefl9bXXt9KCnCr0AkXCLihpB8IyIKJnAg4oqCImRlY29kZWQ6XHQiIERlY29kZSAiwqPCsS0xwrjChy7DjMKlwrPCsMKIMcKfwqXCnyzCo8K_KMK1wogxwqUrMjU2KSIg4oqCK0BcMOKHoTEyOSIuLOKItjviiJjCrMKxwq_ijLXiiJril4vijIrijIjigYU94omgPOKJpD7iiaUrLcOXw7fil7_igb_igpnihqfihqXiiKDip7vilrPih6HiiqLih4zima3ii6_ijYnijY_ijZbiipriipviip3ilqHiipTiiYXiip_iioLiio_iiqHihq_ihpnihpjihrvil6vilr3ijJXiiIriipcv4oinXFziiLXiiaHiiLriip7iiqDijaXiipXiipziiKniipPiioPiipnii4XijZjijZzijZrirJonP-KNo-KNpCHijovihqzimoLOt8-Az4TiiJ5-X1tde30oKcKvQCRcIuKGkHwjIg==)

```
=1-⧻⊃⊝⧻
```

[Try it!](https://uiua.org/pad?src=ZiDihpAgPTEt4qe74oqD4oqd4qe7CgpmIFsxIDFdCmYgWzEgMiAxXQpmIFsxIDYgMyA0IDQgNyA5XQpmIFswXQpmIFsxIDEgMV0KZiBbMSAxIDEgMl0KZiBbMSAxIDIgMl0KZiBbMiAxIDIgMSAyXQpmIFsxIDIgMyA0IDVd)

```
=1-⧻⊃⊝⧻
    ⊃⊝⧻  # length and unique elements of input
   ⧻     # length (of unique elements)
  -      # subtract
=1       # is it equal to one?
```

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, 7 bytes

```
â Ê¶UÊÉ
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=4iDKtlXKyQ==&input=WzEsNiwzLDQsNCw3LDld)

---

### Explanation

Remove duplicates (`â`), get length (`Ê`) and compare equality (`¶`) with the length (`Ê`) of the input (`U`) minus 1 (`É`).

Comment: Isn't that 12 bytes? Aren't `âÊÉ¶` multibyte characters?

Answer (score 1):

## [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/) + coreutils, 36 bytes

```bash
sort|uniq -dc|grep -Pqz '^ *2 .*\n$'
```

Output is via exit code, where **0** is success (truthy) and **1** is failure (falsy).

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/vzi/qKSmNC@zUEE3JbkmvSi1QEE3oLBKQT1OQctIQU8rJk9F/f9/Qy4zLmMuEyA057IEAA)

Answer (score 1):

## C (GCC), <s>80</s> 78 bytes

```
i,j,t;f(x,l)int*x;{for(i=t=0;i<l;++i)for(j=0;j<i;)t+=x[i]==x[j++];return!~-t;}
```

-1 thanks to Jonathan Frech

-1 thanks to Kevin Cruijssen

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##jc/dCoIwFAfw63qKJQSbO0Lz42ruScwLWWkbtmKsEMRe3eagW@3mcM724885MumknGcFGhxv8QA9UcbFAx/bh8VKOHHiquw5pYosL9rPulScOCqGStXCV01pze3Vvaw5fBLHp9lHoHujDF6axnYSkLw1FsWxH94Ejfvd0/q/FkfHy9lEgFq82KomIwM2AUoJ4asoDSxbZydP2FYS@ycpMEg9zNdhCmG3QIvtIzLIofjRaf4C)

`f` is a function that takes in an `int*` pointing to the list, and an `int` that is the length of the list, and returns 1 if there are exactly two equal entries and all other entries are distinct, and 0 value otherwise.

The function checks all pairs of numbers in the list, counting the number of pairs, and returns whether the number of pairs is 1.

Comment: `return 1==t;` can be `return!~-t;` to save a byte.

Comment: `j<i;++j)t+=x[i]==x[j]` can be `j<i;)t+=x[i]==x[j++]` to save a byte.

Comment: [73 bytes](https://tio.run/##jc/dCsIgFADg63oKGwQ6jpC2XYlPsnYxLJeyLMRiMPbsS4Vut27k/HzncFS0V2pZDFgIQuMRBmJcKEcx6afHQTIwchCGUkFSwUojbEoClWNjWhlf2wp/C2/vDkHMS5xGj844nILO9wqQuncelWVMPgRN@93Lx57GxfF6cQUgjZNtWjIxYDMgTohYRTyz8zo7RcK2NrF/NmUGPMJqHXLIt2Vab3/iDBXUPzovXw "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>46</s> 44 bytes

```java
l->l.stream().distinct().count()==l.size()-1
```

-2 bytes thanks to *@Nevay*. (Old answer: `l->new java.util.HashSet(l).size()==l.size()-1`)

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##tZI9b8MgEIb3/IobsWSj2v1S5ThS9jZLxqrDBZMKFx@WwanSyr/dPSetKnXoFDgQH@/x8IJo8ICZ6zQ19dukLHoPT2jocwFgKOh@j0rDZp4C7JyzGgmUaHiXHIKx8tH4ADYpOWHkxtUHDEbBBggqmGy2stKHXmMrEllztiEVeKjcQNxXFcvmQ4sky6fyTOiGnWXCN@jgTA0texLb0Bt6fX4BTM6GtkcfdCvdEGTHUrAkSCpB@h1@Ha77Ho@zzeVK/Fn1Ev2siDzNEy7lpalFJO5dep3ecNynD//yL33yVZTbxHr9OYpI5CIKuTiRY7kuTr/m9oc9LsbpCw)

```java
l->                // Method with List parameter and boolean return-type
  l.stream()       //  Stream over the List
   .distinct()     //  ignoring all duplicated items
   .count()        //  and get the total amount of non-duplicated items in the List
     ==            //   And check if it's size is equals to
       l.size()-1  //   the size of the input-list - 1
                   // End of method (implicit / single-line return-statement)
```

Comment: 44 bytes: `l->l.stream().distinct().count()==l.size()-1`

Answer (score 1):

## Bash, <s>36</s>, 35 bytes

```
for k;{ H[$k]=;};((${#H[@]}+1==$#))
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##S0oszvhfnFqiYKhgpGCsYAKkjf@n5RcpZFtXK3hEq2TH2hpa11praKhUK3tEO8TWahva2qooa2r@/w8A) exit status 0: true, 1: false, `((..))` can be changed to `echo $((..))`, to see boolean value (1:true, 0:false)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), 31 bytes

```clj
#(=(count(set %))(-(count %)1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87JzyotSv2vkZtYUKagkZyfW6BQUJSZV5KT919ZwxYoUJpXolGcWqKgqqmpkZKaDBEB8TT/a3JFRxsqGMZyKQApIxjDTMFYwQQIzRUsQQIGEFG4OhA0gjGNIEwjMBMubgQ2wTQ2VvM/AA)

Does the same as [LyricLy's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145032/75204)

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Comment: Thanks! Hope this answer is ok, I felt like I was misusing TIO haha

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 7 bytes

```js
ÊÉ¶Uâ Ê
      Ê // Return whether the number of
   Uâ   // unique items in the input
  ¶     // is equal to
ÊÉ      // the input's length minus one.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn//3DX4c5D20IPL1I43PX/f7ShjpmOsY4JEFrGAgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 7 bytes

```
dl.&l-₁
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pf/ahtw6Ompkcdy5VKikpTlfRqQMy0xJziVKXa04vK/6fk6Knl6D5qavz/PzraUMcwVgdIGkFpMx1jHRMgNNexBPINwGIwNSBoBGUZgVlGYBZM1Ais1zQ2FgA)

Truthy/falsy input is achieved through predicate success/failure, as if this predicate is run as the entire program on a single input, it will print `true.` if it succeeds and `false.` if it fails. The header on TIO is there so you can run all of the cases at once.

```
dl         The length of the input with duplicates removed
  .        is the output variable,
   &       and
    l-₁    so is the length of the input minus 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

## Regex (ECMAScript), <s>69</s> 67 bytes

The input is in the form of a comma-delimited list of nonnegative integers in decimal.

```
^(?=.*\b(\w+\b).*,\1\b)(?!(.*\b\1\b){3}|.*\b(?!\1\b)(\w+\b).*,\3\b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzdboMwDIXveQq4wmaU8tN1Gijjai@wXQKTKE1athRQCOvars/OQlo0WfI59vnsz/K77CtRd3LRd/WWikPbfNHTKEhDj@Yb3b3@dABn8rJ0xg9IiefkG8iPD/kGPcfNA6WQWjCt9XCJrr@aSa1b@M9GSkdneUZPtu9S1M0O0Ot5XVFYu4sVYsJaAYwECXAiaLnldUMB0SLNwHnCiI@XmoHFsFPHEjAx1MgzvyDEzmzsBtlLAdw7lLLag8DUlmKgsWnasc1K3itrYzJjmFxHlcv9KTaywA2KqYd3XbuRu1L15D4XhqGPJ8zX4QxPFd5dqF2o3bwN9ZPH4g8)

```
^
(?=
    .*\b(\w+\b)          # \1 = an element that occurs at least twice
    .*,\1\b              # locate the second occurrence of \1; since there's at least one
                         # element before it, it's guaranteed to have a commma in front
)
(?!
    (.*\b\1\b){3}        # Assert that \1 does not occur 3 or more times
|
    .*\b(?!\1\b)(\w+\b)  # \3 = any element that's different from \1
    .*,\3\b              # Assert that \3 does not occur again; since there's at least one
                         # element before it, it's guaranteed to have a commma in front
)
```

## Regex (ECMAScript), <s>67</s> 65 bytes

```
^(?=.*(\bx+\b).*,\1\b)(?!(.*\b\1\b){3}|.*\b(?!\1\b)(x+\b).*,\3\b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVDBbtswDL37K5xeJDqOaztp10bVctqhlx62o@MCSiI7WhXZkJXMbeZvz2TFaTtgwEBAJB8fH0X@ZAfWrLWozaSpxYbrXaVe@OtJU8V/@d95@a2tMX6jX6@D0zNe0CjAy1U7Xq4gCsJlYj1ejHAULFcuOU67331iwXPxnTq1/hRcv0Fkqh9GC1ViiBop1hzfhpMZADnQq0d1YFJsfKHqvZlfkaLSuKAJwZJqzjZSKI4BRlTtpSQFjeEoCjwqoLZ6BgPxbCqzOB9RlCGwGo3RWALhsuE9VQ4TJ4kVQTmC48A5APlgrytlhNpz0pX00pGEtsfp45KWUVNLYTAKEUAkuSrN9iH5n5jXbyNoHLYUISIeyqGTiPHYLSKaJ/aEGa2ZbvijXajMRA7wb93WnmVlj/JCur4V2jG13yG9a1Gkec2ZwQzsWFtuR/Tje220Y2a9xRqoO@QCFczeZ@6jOTJ6bwMffZ7Udd3J4mb7OveyJEzy/k0HfxtOw5m1L@F97vmeU3I8V72we0uHKHVR6qILmjqVm9zzdpXm/vu02aCfxOcBWeyAmzNg@dldePc349yS9MC9Bf4A)

This is a straight port of the decimal version to positive unary, changing both occurrences of `\w+` to `x+`. Input is a list of positive unary numbers separated by `,`. Each one is a string of `x`s whose length represents the number.

## Regex (ECMAScript), 92 bytes

This version fully supports nonnegative unary. That is very costly; `\b` can no longer be used at all. The part that ballooned the most in length was where it's asserted that no element other than `\2` is repeated 3 or more times, because with a simple `{3}` loop, it would get a false negative due to falsely finding a repeated zero consisting of 3 repeated zero-width matches with no commas consumed.

```
^(?=.*(^|,)(x*(?!x)).*,\2(?!x))(?!.*(^|,)(\2(?!x)(.*,\2(?!x)){2}|(?!\2(?!x))(x*(?!x)).*,\6(?!x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##hVBNc9owEL37V5hcpAXhYIfQBEXNqYdccmiP1JlxQTZqhPHIgjoh/u10JZuQdjrT0Yz09Pbt24@f2T6rl0ZVdlxXaiXNZls@y5ejEaX8FX6VxZemovRVfL4cHp/ovYiG9OmNAW2G9H7QAERD9j3pIN6nKFKe81E4JO0bft91H3Nn0OHj8PIVIrv9Zo0qCwpRrdVS0hkbTwH4Xlw8lPtMq1Woympn5xc83xqai5hTLYzMVlqVkgIMRLnTmudiAgeV00EOFfpZCjzAr15M0oEgCwLoUVtDNXCpa@mkuq84jtGEpAQOvWYP/Kxebkuryp3kbSFOGTHDHO9PC1FEdaWVpYQRHFDLsrDru/h/ZoGbRokJawQhXN0VfSZXo5EfRNWP2SPNRJWZWj7gQMVCpQD/9m1wLT9wKc@8danQjAS2w93TkMjISmaWZoBlMdwMxLm9JtpkdrmmBoRf5D3JM9zPPCRzYs0OQUg@Vmrb9oi8Xb/Mg0XM4tTdSf/O2BWb4vnEbtMgDLyT00189KR2J@lR4lHi0YlNvMt1GgSbrZHhe7UJcz54s7gDcce4h50ZFvsyiUNXnp/2jWHUd4ZCR1x3BBZa3LCbPxVdSuyIW0d0rZwH@rsi/n4D)

```
^
(?=
    .*(^|,)(x*(?!x))          # \2 = an element that occurs at least twice
    .*,\2(?!x)                # locate the second occurrence of \2; since there's at least one
                              # element before it, it's guaranteed to have a commma in front
)
(?!
    .*(^|,)
    (
        \2((?!x).*,\2){2}     # Assert that \2 does not occur 3 or more times
    |
        (?!\2(?!x))(x*(?!x))  # \6 = any element that's different from \2
        .*,\6                 # Assert that \6 does not occur again; since there's at least one
                              # element before it, it's guaranteed to have a commma in front
    )
    (?!x)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
QṁƑḊ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/w4c7GYxMf7uj6f7j9UdOayP//o6MNdQxjdbiAlBGMYaZjrGMChOY6liABA4goXB0IGsGYRhCmEZgJFzcCm2AaGwsA)

```
Q       Is the input uniquified
 ṁƑ     the same length as
   Ḋ    the input without its first element?
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 26 bytes

```
(l=Length)@Union@#+1==l@#&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n277XyPH1ic1L70kQ9MhNC8zP89BWdvQ1jbHQVntf0BRZl6JgkN6dLWhjmFtLBcy3whDxEzHWMcECM11LFFkDNDUYZoFgkYYYkZoYkZgMUyVRmB7TWtj//8HAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Convex](https://github.com/GamrCorps/Convex), 7 bytes

```
_Å,)\,=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S87PK0ut@P8//nCrjmaMju3///@jDRXMFIwVTIDQXMEyFgA)

Answer (score 0):

### Batch, 109 bytes

```
@set/ap=1,s=0
@for %%x in (%*)do @(for %%y in (%*)do @set/a"s+=!(%%x-%%y)")&set/ap*=s,s=0
@if %p%==4 echo 1
```

Port of @DJMcMayhem's answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 5, 25+1 (-p)=26 bytes

```
$H{$_}=1}{$\=$.-1==keys%H
```

[TIO](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/Fo1olvtbWsLZaJcZWRU/X0NY2O7WyWNXj/39DLiMuQy5jIPkvv6AkMz@v@L9uAQA)

Answer (score 0):

## Batch, 131

```
set b=,%*,
goto j
:l
call set f=%%b:,%1,=,#,%%
if "%b%"=="%f%" exit 1
set b=%f%
goto:eof
:j
FOR %%A IN (%b%) DO call :l %%A
```

The `%errorlevel%` can be checked for the result. it works by tokenising the input, `FOR %%A IN (%b%) DO call :l %%A` every instance of that token + to commas is then replaced in a copy of the input with a ",#," `call set f=%%b:,%1,=,#,%%` the resulting string is then compared to the copy of the previous string. If there is no change in the string, it is because that number has already occured.

`c:\>batfile.bat 1,2,3`

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 12 bytes

```
{.Set+1==$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/Wi84tUTb0NZWJb72v7VCcWKlglJ1mgKQZwUklBTS8osUbAwVDO10QJQRjGGmYKxgAoTmCpYgAQOIKFQdUJUCGNtZ/wcA)

Convert to Set, test if the number of elements is less by one.

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 40 bytes

```r
sum(outer(x<-scan(),x,"=="))==2+sum(x|1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/v7g0VyO/tCS1SKPCRrc4OTFPQ1OnQkfJ1lZJU9PW1kgbJF9RY6j531DBTMFYwQQIzRUs/wMA)

Approach is different from [the other `R` solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/145056/80010) - and not as golfy...

Comment: Nit's Japt answer can (I think) be ported but using `unique` is certainly close-ish to `duplicated`

Answer (score 0):

## 12-basic, 31 bytes

```
FUNC S(L)?LEN(L|L)==LEN(L)-1END
```

The `|` (union) operator returns an array containing elements that are in both of the input arrays. As a side effect, it removes duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 16 bytes

```
a->#a==#Set(a)+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7P1HXTjnR1lY5OLVEI1FT2/B/YkFBTqVGooKunUJBUWYeUFRBCcRRUkgDKtDUUYiONtQxjAXShjpGMIaZjrGOCRCa61iCBAwgonB1IGgEYxpBmEZgJlzcCGyCaWys5n8A)

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 38 bytes

Not quite as golfed as another R answer, but a different approach.

```r
length(a<-scan())-length(unique(a))==1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/Pyc1L70kQyPRRrc4OTFPQ1NTFypSmpdZWJqqkaipaWtr@N9QwUjBWMFEwfA/AA)

Answer (score 0):

### F#, 49 bytes

```
let s c=Seq.distinct c|>Seq.length=Seq.length c-1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY9NC8IwDIbv/RVBEBScbPULmSt48C543DzM2s1C7WYXBcH/Pluds00P79Mkb5qiCXhlRNsqgdAATw7iNj3LBqXmCPzFHCuhS7wkfwk8iNp0s9NonvtKamRH4gyuudSQm/IBCYGUgD1pFEfHn6KeXsazeG5jFa@7t7DP@T0uqEe0J/ohP0s/ngvL9r4YuB9f8xpGxV0Dr5QSHGWlIWAeTdzePY37RonCfDtHfrERzV3h2HnUxq5eaBgMtxkGLMPhaeCP6UoJgbB9Aw)

`Seq.distinct` creates a sequence of all the unique elements in the collection. If the number of distinct elements is one less than the original collection, there are soulmates.

Answer (score 0):

## Javascript,96 bytes

```
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)for(j=0;j<a.length;j++)(a[i]==a[j]&& i!=j)?count++:0 console.log(count==2)
```

And a better readable format

```
for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
  for(j=0;j<a.length;j++){
   (a[i]==a[j]&& i!=j)?count++:0
  }
}
 console.log(count==2)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 7 bytes

```
.,\.&,-
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPkfbahgqGCqYKJgHPtfTydGT01H9/9/AA)

```
.,\.&,- # Stack will be show as [], with L being our list.
.       # Duplicate array [L L]
 ,      # Size of top element [L N]
  \     # Swap the positions of the top two elements [N L]
   .&   # Listwise OR (remove duplicates) [N L&]
     ,  # Size of top elements (should be 1 lesser) [N N-1?]
      - # Difference

Output is 1 if TRUE. Any other result is FALSE.
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 25 bytes

```
[ duplicates length 1 = ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VU9NC8IwDL33V8Q/IK5@oeJZvHgRT@Kh1MyN1Vrb7DDGfnuNY8qaQMh7vJdHcqXp5ePlfDwdtlCht2ggIAUe7xqtxgDOI1HjfGkJdkK0ArgmQL6moulBCxl3999lglYwhwX3GjbMDu5cmYA/92ykTi9l/bUxliMshyyZZH/Tlsx08Qr32plSK@I3DNoHFazYwy0@lYNASlfT@AE)

### Explanation

It's a quotation (anonymous function) that takes a sequence as input and leaves a boolean as output. Assuming `{ 1 6 3 4 4 7 9 }` is on top of the data stack when this quotation is called...

- `duplicates` Obtain a list of duplicate values. **Stack:** `{ 4 }`
- `length` Get the length. **Stack:** `1`
- `1` Push `1` to the stack. **Stack:** `1 1`
- `=` Return `t` if the top two objects on the data stack are equal, otherwise return `f`. **Stack:** `t`